# lib java para consultar hardware

Tags: java

estou querendo verificar em uma VM minha na amazon se o hardware que comprei é realmente o que eles me oferecem.
Gostaria de fazer um framework ou API apenas para verificar a quantidade de memoria, HD e processador.

Alguem sabe me dizer qual a biblioteca JAVA que me permite fazer este tipo de consulta?

Agradeço a qualquer um que me ajudar.

Comment: Não tem um painel onde você possa ver isso?

Comment: Renan, ter tem, contudo quero confirmar isso se de fato é o que me mostram. por isso estou pedindo ajuda pois nunca programei algo desse tipo antes, no máximo foi o console em C para executar comandos do windows mesmo para ver status da rede e etc.

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso em Java, mas encontrei uma pergunta no SOen com várias respostas. Acho que nenhuma resposta sozinha resolve o seu problema, mas juntando um pouco de cada uma acho que você já terá meio caminho andado. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information - boa sorte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar as chamadas de Runtime.getRunTime().
Esse [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information) tem bastante informação sobre o assunto, pode te ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, de fato isso era exatamente o que queria. Ajudou mesmo Dans, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a tua melhor opção é pegar uma biblioteca da linguagem C que faz o que você deseja, neste caso, ter acesso ao hardware e usar ela no teu projeto Java através de uma chamada nativa. No site da Caelum há um tutorial sobre isto: http://blog.caelum.com.br/escrevendo-metodos-nativos-em-java-com-jni-e-jna/

Comment: vou checar aqui. obrigado pela sugestão.